# dispatch_async with c++ instance - app crashes

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

I want to use `Tesseract` in my Mac App, but recognizing text blocks the complete application. Therefore I tried to use a `dispatch_async`, but my app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (at "tess->Recognize(0)".
Here is the method, I'm using:

```
- (void)getText:(void(^)(NSString *response))handler {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        tess->Recognize(0);
        char *text = tess->GetUTF8Text();
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:text];
        delete [] text;
        handler(string);
    });
}
```

I think it's a problem with ARC and the c++ instance of tesseract. Using `__block` didn't help.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the working code. Hopefully this will maybe help somebody.

*AppDelegate.m*

```
...
[self processPage:myImage withCompletionHandler:^(NSString *text) {
    NSLog(@"%@", text);
}];
...

- (void)processPage:(NSImage*)image withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSString *text))completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        Tesseract *tess = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"deu"];
        [tess setImageWithImage:image];
        NSString *text = [tess getText];
        completion(text);
    });
}
```

*Tesseract.mm*

```
- (NSString*)getText {
    tess->Recognize(0);
    char *text = tess->GetUTF8Text();
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:text];
    delete [] text;
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Does it work without block?

Comment: Yes, no problem without dispatch_async (instead of the fact, that the application is blocked)

Comment: I believe you know that if you are doing anything with the string in your handler for UI components, like setting the string to any ui components etc, it should be done on the main thread.

Comment: You should show where you create "tess." -- I have a hard time believing it's an ARC problem if tess doesn't inherit from NSObject.  Tess wouldn't even have a referenceCount for ARC to mangle.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help.

I recently found the solution. I did the complete code where I create my Tesseract class and where I call the getText method into the dispatch block. Now it works.

Comment: Please update your answer to include your working code! Otherwise anyone who comes across this question in the future won’t benefit from what you’ve learned.